# Get XML from webservice with static fallback value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am attempting to use the jQuery $.ajax call to return xml from a web service. If the call to this web service fails, for whatever reason, I have some static xml that i want to use. I am trying to use the timeout property to tell me if the call has failed or not and have put the xml parsing logic in my error function. I know the parsing of the xml works fine because I have tested it with the ajax call removed. When I add the ajax call with a dummy url to force an error, the $xml var never gets set. Any thoughts?

```
var navXml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><book><chapter id="1"></book>'; //static xml here
var serviceUrl = 'http://1234lkjasdf/test'; //bad service url to test failure
var $xml;

$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'xml',
url: serviceUrl,
timeout: 10,
success: function(data, status){
    //set $xml var to xml data returned
    $xml = data;
},
error: function (req, status, error){
    //set $xml var to xml parsed from static value
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( navXml ), 
        $xml = $( xmlDoc );
}
});
```

Comment: I found the problem, my ajax call was being made asynchronously so while it was waiting for the timeout to set the $xml variable, the rest of the code was executing. So the rest of my code was executing while the $xml variable was still null. I just added the async property to my ajax call and set it to false to fix this. Although after some more research it looks like I should use the $.wait() method instead of breaking the async nature of ajax as a best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

Looks like any error in $.ajax error handler silently fails. You have an error in your XML. Your chapter tag isn't closed. It needs to be:

```
<chapter id="1" />
```

When I fix the error in XML, it works. Here's a fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/Pzdv5/1/

---

Your error handler needs to look like this:

```
//set $xml var to xml parsed from static value
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( navXml ); 
$xml = $( xmlDoc );
```

You are missing **var** in front of `xmlDoc` (will create a global variable), and more importantly, you have comma (,) instead of semicolon (;) after the `xmlDoc` declaration.

Comment: that didn't work for me either. Actually, I have tested the original logic outside the error handler and it works fine (not declaring xmlDoc and the comma after the first line).

Comment: have you tested whether it even gets to the error handler? console.log(error), or something?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but that wasn't it either (I replaced the xml string i'm using since it's huge). It was actually the fact that the ajax call runs asynchronously so the rest of the code was executing before the variable is populated. Thanks for the help though!